# Determining position of tableHeaderView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am making a custom header view on my tableview. The custom view has a gradient on it.

I only want that gradient to show if it is the only header visible.

So if a user is scrolling and happens to see two sections of the tableview, the second section on the tableview should not have a gradient.

What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking about the `tableHeaderView` property or the view used in `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`?

Comment: tableView:viewForHeaderInSection

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts:

Perhaps in your table's delegate, you can cache the header views, and every time one is requested, check it's peers to see if they are on screen (determined by UIView's .window property being non-nil).

```
- (UIView *)tableView:tableView viewForHeaderInSection:section {
    if([_headerViews objectAtIndex:section-1].window ||  [_headerViews objectAtIndex:section+1].window) {
        // there are peers on screen
    } else {
        // this is the only one onscreen
    }
}
```

This is just sample code, and does not ensure that the views are properly initialized, etc. just an idea.